# Can we create custom HTTP description?

Tags: php, rest, http

I just want to know if we can change HTTP response name,
like for example `header('HTTP/1.1 500 Cannot connect to database');`
Or should it be `500 Internal server error` and message in body?
I found answer.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6.1.1
"The Status-Code is intended
for use by automata and the Reason-Phrase is intended for the human
user. The client is not required to examine or display the Reason-
Phrase."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `header('HTTP/1.1 500 Cannot connect to database');` would work, see the example at http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php#107261:

```
header($protocol . ' ' . $code . ' ' . $text);
```

Comment: I ask, is that right. I know that works. But never saw that someone changing http text. Im still searching for any info at RCF's. But i can't find it.

Comment: Ohh i found http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-6.1.1 "The Status-Code is intended
   for use by automata and the Reason-Phrase is intended for the human
   user. The client is not required to examine or display the Reason-
   Phrase."